# Android Studio: Bitmap animation is too fast

Tags: java, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I'll start by saying that I'm a beginner with Android Studio.

I'm trying to draw 3 animations on my screen (depending on the direction the player moves: forward, left or right), consisting of 3 bitmaps images each, but the animation goes too fast.
The curious thing is that I've written 2 methods that basically do the same thing, but with the first one, the animation goes at an ok speed, while with the second method it goes too fast.

First method that gives me the correct speed:

```
Bitmap getImage(){
        if(imgCounter==0){
            imgCounter++;
            if(left){
                return image_left_1;
            }else if(right){
                return image_right_1;
            }else{
                return image_forward_1;
            }
        }else if(imgCounter==1){
            imgCounter++;
            if(left){
                return image_left_2;
            }else if(right){
                return image_right_2;
            }else{
                return image_forward_2;
            }
        }else if(imgCounter==2){
            imgCounter++;
            if(left){
                return image_left_3;
            }else if(right){
                return image_right_3;
            }else{
                return image_standing_3;
            }
        }

        imgCounter=0;
        if(left){
            return image_left_1;
        }else if(right){
            return image_right_1;
        }else{
            return image_forward_1;
        }

    }
```

Second method that makes the animation go too fast:

```
    Bitmap getImage2() {

        num_images=2;
        bitmap_array_left= new Bitmap[]{image_left_1, image_left_2, image_left_3};
        bitmap_array_right= new Bitmap[]{image_right_1, image_right_2, image_right_3};
        bitmap_array_forward= new Bitmap[]{image_forward_1, image_forward_2,image_forward_3};

        for (int i = counter; i <= num_images; i++) {
            if (i == num_images) {
                counter = 0;
                if (left) {
                    return bitmap_array_left[num_images];
                } else if (right) {
                    return bitmap_array_right[num_images];
                } else {
                    return bitmap_array_forward[num_images];
                }
            }

            counter++;
            if (left) {
                return bitmap_array_left[i];
            } else if (right) {
                return bitmap_array_right[i];
            } else {
                return bitmap_array_forward[i];
            }

        }

        return bitmap_array_forward[0];
    }
```

Why am I getting two different speeds if the code does the same thing?
And how can I lower the speed of the animation in the second method?

Comment: Don't you return the first image twice in a row in the first example?

Comment: You're right. I tried to add another image_left_1, image_right_1, image_forward_1 in the bitmap arrays, to see if the animation would slow down, but it's always too fast.
I'm still getting these different speeds...

Comment: I tried to delete that extra return in the first method, and the speeds are now the same. (speed is too fast in both methods)
I really don't understand why if I add another image in the array doesn't give me the same result/speed of the extra return in the first method. :(

Comment: Do you have a fixed framerate in the game? Something like "doing a redraw every 1/60th of a second"? I think maybe you'd have to tie the animation to the current frame, e.g. if it is 1 second long, keep the first pic for the first 20 frames, then call your method to swap on frame 21, keep until 40 etc. Btw. faster or not the second loop is a lot better as it can scale easily.

Comment: I basically have a loop of the methods: update() that changes the position of the images on x and y axes, draw(), and sleep() that stops the thread for 35 milliseconds before calling the update() method again.
The problem is that i have many different animations and some of them go too slow if I put a value>35 in the sleep() method.
So I was wondering if there was a way to just slow down some animations but not others.
And yeah, I really prefer to use the second method!

Comment: 35 still is less than 30 FPS, maybe you can choose a faster baseline. I would try the approach with duplicating animation frames then. Your animation will most likely always be tied to a multiple of a frame drawn, it would probably be problematic to have the game at 60 FPS and the animations at 37 FPS (as an exampele)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and duplicated the frames of the animations. It's a lot better now, thanks for your help! :)